# How to prove the adjoint representation of $\text{SL}_2$ is irreducible when $\text{char}(k) \ne 2$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Consider the adjoint representation of $\text{SL}_2$, where it acts by conjugation on its Lie algebra of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & -a \\ \end{pmatrix}$, and suppose we look at it over a field $k$ with  $\text{char}(k) \ne 2$. Is there a quick way to prove that this representation is then irreducible? Also, is there a quick way to see why it fails to be irreducible when $\text{char}(k) = 2$?

Comment: As a note, you should probably tag this with algebraic groups rather than Lie groups, since the former is the context you need to even work in positive characteristic.

Comment: Thanks, I made the change.

Answer (score 3):

> **Partial Answer:** I'm not sure about semi-simplicity in positive characteristic, so this answer is incomplete. Any proper nontrivial submodule of the adjoint representation has dimension $2$ or $1$. I will show that there are no $1$-dimensional submodules. One also needs to check that there are no $2$-dimensional submodules (unless someone has a slick proof that this doesn't need to be checked).

First, we check that the adjoint representation is **not** irreducible when $\mathrm{char}(k)=2$. Let 
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}_2(k),\;\;ad-bc=1.$$
Then, the matrix for $Ad(X)$ in the basis 
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\;\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
is
$$Ad(X)=\begin{pmatrix}ad+bc&-ac&bd\\-2ab&a^2&-b^2\\2cd&-c^2&d^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-ac&bd\\0&a^2&-b^2\\0&-c^2&d^2\end{pmatrix}$$
so the span of $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ is a $1$-dimensional submodule. (Note that we used $$ad+bc=(1+bc)+bc=1+2bc=1$$ as $\mathrm{char}(k)=2$.)

Now, assume $\mathrm{char}(k)\neq 2$. Note that since the adjoint representation is $3$-dimensional a proper submodule is either $1$-dimensional or $2$-dimensional. I will show that it contains no $1$-dimensional submodules. Indeed, suppose
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\gamma&-\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$
spans a 1-dimensional submodule. Then $v$ is an eigenvector for every $X\in \mathrm{SL}_2(k)$:

> $$Ad(X)(v)=\lambda_Xv\;\;\;\mbox{for some }\lambda_X\in k^\times.$$

Take $X=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and compute $Ad(X)(v)=-\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\gamma\\\beta&-\alpha\end{pmatrix}$. Therefore, $\lambda_X=-1$ and $\gamma=\beta$.

Now, $v=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\beta&-\alpha\end{pmatrix}$. Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $Ad(X)(v)=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha+\beta&-2\alpha\\\beta&-(\alpha+\beta)\end{pmatrix}$. Then, by comparing the $(2,1)$-entries of $Ad(X)(v)$ and $v$, we have $\lambda_X=1$. Therefore, $\alpha=\alpha+\beta$, so $\beta=0$. Finally, we have $\beta=-2\alpha$. Since $\mathrm{char}(k)\neq 2$, $\alpha=0$. Since $v=0$, it does not span a $1$-dimensional submodules.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That almost solves it.

Comment: I can show that this suffices by applying some more advanced stuff (the highest weight is smaller than the characteristic which implies being semisimple). But at that point one might as well note that the dimension is correct for the irreducible of that highest weight.

Comment: @user514014 My advanced argument also provides an "easy" way to see that it fails in characeristic $2$, again by noting that the dimension is wrong for the highest weight.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Isn't the *easiest* way to see that the representation is not irreducible to note that, in characteristic $2$, $h$ is the identity matrix and obviously spans an invariant subspace. (I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't use that argument.)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As far as slick proofs go, I had in mind identifying the dual representation and showing IT doesn't have a 1-d subspace. I don't know how hard that is, though.

Comment: Probably not too hard, though it would still involve computing something (my version avoid all computations by referring to a few hundred pages of theory, so the computation is probably the more illuminating way).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I assume the dual is the standard representation. Is that hard to see? If not, then the result is clear since the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: I am not sure which you mean to be the standard representation. When it is irreducible, it is both the standard and costandard representation with that highest weight, and presumably it is the standard one in characteristic $2$ (either that or it is decomposable which would surprise me).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ahh, never mind. I am just confusing myself.